# Prove that the partial derivatives of $(y-g_i+a\sum^n_{j=1} g_j)$ are positive

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, summation, partial-derivative, game-theory

I have a function:

$$\pi_i^1=y-g_i+a\sum^n_{j=1}g_j,$$

where 0 < a<1< na,

and I need to prove this:
$$\frac{\partial(\sum^n_{i=1}\pi^1_i)}{\partial g_i}=-1+na>0.$$

I am not very experienced with summations to be confident in doing this.

This is what I have done so far (below), but I am not sure it is correct. Can anyone help?
$$\sum^n_{i=1}\pi_i=\sum^n_{i=1}y-\sum^n_{i=1}g_i+\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}ag_j\\
=ny-\left(g_i+\sum^n_{j\ne i}g_j\right)+a\sum^n_{j=1}ng_j\\
=ny-\left(g_i+\sum^n_{j\ne i}g_j\right)+na\sum^n_{j=1}g_j\\
=ny-\left(g_i+\sum^n_{j\ne i}g_j\right)+na(g_i+\sum^n_{j\ne i}g_j)$$